# Python 3: pyzipcode is not support in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to pip install `pyzipcode` using Python 3, and I'm getting the following error. Is there a way that I can fix this problem.

```
Collecting pysqlite (from pyzipcode==1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading pysqlite-2.8.3.tar.gz (80kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 5.8MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library.
```

Comment: There appears to be a Python 3 compatible fork of `pyzipcode`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcode3

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing same issue, I installed it using:

```
pip install pyzipcode3
```

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
pip3 install pyzipcode3
```

This worked for me as well